# Why keras not returning the layer for me?

Tags: keras

Here is a simple code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(784, ))
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dense(10))

for l in model.layers:
    print(l.name)
    print(model.get_layer(l.name))
```

Here is the output I got:

```
dense_1
<keras.layers.core.Dense object at 0x0000000027CC2128>
dense_2
None
dense_3
None
```

Which is quite awkward, I mean I have 3 dense layers, the names are listed correctly, but why does `model.get_layer()` function not returning the other 2 dense layers instance for me?

Comment: Tryied running this code on my pc and it works as expected. What version of keras are you using?

Comment: @gionni, I'm using keras version 2.0.5 in Anaconda 3.6 64 bit in Windows.

Comment: I have 2.0.6 version but on ubuntu 16.04